# VMware Tools repo

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I maintain a local repository for all the installation packages. I'm attempting to use reposync (the first time, I generally use rsync to mirror what I need) and I'm getting some odd behavior. Any repos I have enabled system wide at */etc/yum.repos.d/MYREPO.conf* are being pulled in to the list of directories to sync.

```
./reposync -n -c vmware-tools.cfg -p tmp -u
```

I really don't want to provide a list of repos to include - I'd like to simply add the necessary lines to the above file and have it work.

The contents of vmware-tools.cfg.

```
[6-i386]
name=VMware Tools 6 x32
baseurl=http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/rhel6/i386
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[6-x86_64]
name=VMware Tools 6 x64
baseurl=http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/rhel6/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[5-i386]
name=VMware Tools 5 x32
baseurl=http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/rhel5/i386
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[5-x86_64]
name=VMware Tools 5 x64
baseurl=http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/rhel5/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

How do I correct this behavior and / or sync these files in a better fashion?

Comment: So `reposync` is downloading everything in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` instead of just what's in `vmware-tools.cfg`?

Comment: @mgorven- yes, that is it exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `reposync` help:

```
 -r REPOID, --repoid=REPOID
                    specify repo ids to query, can be specified multiple
                    times (default is all enabled)
```

That means you will need to pass the `-r` option to `reposync` and the name of the repo to sync. So, your command should look like the following:

```
./reposync -n -c vmware-tools.cfg -p tmp -r 6-x86_64 -u
```

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the same issue, but found a working solution:

`reposync` -c option is looking for a yum.conf, not a repository definition, so by feeding it a full yum configuration with `repodir` set to nothing it only pulls the required urls:

```
[main]
reposdir=

[vmwaretools-rhel6-i386]
name=VMware Tools 6 x32
baseurl=http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/rhel6/i386
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

...
```

Which results in:

```
[repo@repo reposync-test]# reposync -c reposync-yum.conf -p repos -u
vmwaretools-rhel5-i386                                                                                                                                  |  951 B     00:00
vmwaretools-rhel5-i386/primary                                                                                                                          |  17 kB     00:00
vmwaretools-rhel5-x86_64                                                                                                                                |  951 B     00:00
vmwaretools-rhel5-x86_64/primary                                                                                                                        |  13 kB     00:00
vmwaretools-rhel6-i386                                                                                                                                  |  951 B     00:00
vmwaretools-rhel6-i386/primary                                                                                                                          |  17 kB     00:00
vmwaretools-rhel6-x86_64                                                                                                                                |  951 B     00:00
vmwaretools-rhel6-x86_64/primary                                                                                                                        |  17 kB     00:00
http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/rhel5/i386/kmod-vmware-tools-pvscsi-1.1.3.0-2.6.18.8.el5.5.el5.i686.rpm
http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/rhel5/i386/kmod-vmware-tools-pvscsi-PAE-1.1.3.0-2.6.18.8.el5.5.el5.i686.rpm
http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/rhel5/i386/kmod-vmware-tools-vmblock-1.1.2.0-2.6.18.8.el5.5.el5.i686.rpm
...
```